# Insert Unique values into a hash map

Tags: java, hashmap, grouping

I am trying to insert a list of a certain class into a hash map. The key should be one of the fields in the list, in my case the id, and the value of the hash map should be list items that have the key as their id.

Here is an example of what am trying to do:

```
// example class

public class Dog{
  int id,
  int name,
  int foodEaten
}

// getters

// dog objects
Dog dog1 = new Dog(1,"Dog1", "Cheese")
Dog dog2 = new Dog(1,"Dog1", "Meat")

Dog dog3 = new Dog(2,"Dog2", "Fish")
Dog dog4 = new Dog(2,"Dog2", "Milk")

List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();

//insert dog objects into dog list

//Creating HashMap that will have id as the key and dog objects as the values
HashMap<Integer, List<Dog>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This is what am trying to do it

```
for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size()-1; i++) {
  List<Dog> cx = new ArrayList<>();
  if (dog.get(i).getId() == dog.get(i+1).getId()){
    cx.add(dog.get(i));
  }
   map.put(dog.get(i).getId(), cx);
}
```

However, I am getting this as the result:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dog1",
      "foodEaten": "Cheese"
    }
  ],
  "2": []
}
```

But this is what I would like to achieve:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dog1",
      "foodEaten": "Cheese"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dog1",
      "foodEaten": "Meat"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Dog2",
      "foodEaten": "Fish"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Dog2",
      "foodEaten": "Milk"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the same Dog Ids.  How do you decide what dog Id to compare to.  Also, dog4 has dogId == 1.  Is that correct?

Comment: @WJS I have edited dog 4, that was not correct

Comment: Right. And your class is wrong too.  Two of your arguments are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog(1, "Dog1", "Cheese");
Dog dog2 = new Dog(1, "Dog1", "Meat");

Dog dog3 = new Dog(2, "Dog2", "Fish");
Dog dog4 = new Dog(2, "Dog2", "Milk");

List<Dog> dogList = List.of(dog1, dog2, dog3, dog4);
//insert dog objects into dog list
        
//Creating HashMap that will have id as the key and dog objects as the values
Map<Integer, List<Dog>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Dog dog : dogList) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(dog.id, k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(dog);
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
1=[{1, Dog1, Cheese, {1, Dog1, Meat]
2=[{2, Dog2, Fish, {2, Dog2, Milk]
```

The dog class

```
static class Dog {
    
    int id;
    String name;
    String foodEaten;
    
    public Dog(int id, String name, String foodEaten) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.foodEaten = foodEaten;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s, %s, %s", id, name, foodEaten);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Good Answer, learnt something useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Tosh Just curious.  I specifically addressed your question without altering your intended logic (using a for loop).  Why did you unaccept my answer?  Did it not work?

Comment: @WJS I accepted the one I ended up using, but I have accepted yours back, Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Tosh  Please understand that I just wanted to know if there was a problem.  I am not here for reputation but just to help folks.  Please feel free to accept the answer that meets your requirements.  If that was the answer that best served you then by all means accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy(Dog::getId)` to group the dogs with the same `id`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> list = List.of(new Dog(1, "Dog1", "Cheese"), new Dog(1, "Dog1", "Meat"), new Dog(2, "Dog2", "Fish"),
                new Dog(2, "Dog2", "Milk"));

        Map<Integer, List<Dog>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dog::getId));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1=[Dog [id=1, name=Dog1, foodEaten=Cheese], Dog [id=1, name=Dog1, foodEaten=Meat]], 2=[Dog [id=2, name=Dog2, foodEaten=Fish], Dog [id=2, name=Dog2, foodEaten=Milk]]}
```

**The `toString` implementation:**

```
public String toString() {
    return "Dog [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", foodEaten=" + foodEaten + "]";
}
```

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to do it. However, there can be `n` different ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Tosh and welcome to Stackoverflow.

The problem is in your if statement when you check for IDs of your two objects.

```
for (Dog dog : dogList) {
  if(dog.getId() == dog.getId()){
     crMap.put(cr.getIndividualId(), clientReceivables.);
  }
}
```

Here you check IDs of the same object named "dog" and you will always get **True** in this if statement. Thats why it fills your map with all the values for both IDs.

Another problem you have there is that your dog4 has the ID equals to 1 which is ID of dog1 and dog2. With that in mind you still won't achieve what you want, so check that too.

Now for the solution. If you want to go through the list and compare every dog to the next one than you need to write that different. I am not sure if you are just working with java or with android but there is a solution to this and cleaner version of your code.

With Java 8 you got Stream API which can help you with this. Check it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)

Also for android you got android-linq which you can check [here](https://github.com/zbra-solutions/android-linq)